# Message if view returns no results?

Tags: views, 6

I have a view which generates pages based on taxonomy terms. I have set up a navigation which links to each term in my website. Is there a simple way way I can return a default message if the view is empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are looking for *Empty text* under Basic Settings.  This will allow you to set some text (message) that will be displayed if the view returns no results.

[image: Views Empty Text]

You can choose any of your available input filters, the above is just an example.